# Import Class into another Class Component in angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I have repeated code in my project.

I separate it from other component to make it much easier and dynamic when changing some value. Unluckily, It doesn't work with me.

Here's what I have

`Repeated Code: form.ts`

```
export class Form {
    constructor(){
        var today = new Date(),
            dd = today.getDate(),
            mm = today.getMonth() + 1,
            yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd < 10) dd = `0${dd}`;
        if(mm < 10) mm = `0${mm}`;

        today = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;

        this.balance.dateTo = today;
    }

    public balance = {
        viewBy: 'Ad1',
        companyUnit: 'DEPED',
        financialYear: '2016',
        clients: 'Dummy Text 1'
    };
}
```

In other component such as balance, settlement, etc...

I imported it on the top.

Here's what I have tried:

```
import { Form } from '../form';   // path is correct

export class BalanceComponent {
    form: Form;                   // I am not sure of it
                                  // this is the place I want to import repeated class
    search_data(balance){
        console.log(balance);
    }
}
```

systemjs.config.js

```
(function (global) {
  System.config({
    paths: {
      // paths serve as alias
      'npm:': 'node_modules/'
    },
    // map tells the System loader where to look for things
    map: {
      // our app is within the app folder
      app: 'app',
      // angular bundles
      '@angular/core': 'npm:@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js',
      '@angular/common': 'npm:@angular/common/bundles/common.umd.js',
      '@angular/compiler': 'npm:@angular/compiler/bundles/compiler.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser/bundles/platform-browser.umd.js',
      '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic': 'npm:@angular/platform-browser-dynamic/bundles/platform-browser-dynamic.umd.js',
      '@angular/http': 'npm:@angular/http/bundles/http.umd.js',
      '@angular/router': 'npm:@angular/router/bundles/router.umd.js',
      '@angular/forms': 'npm:@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js',
      'ng2-pagination': 'npm:/ng2-pagination',
      // other libraries
      'rxjs':                      'npm:rxjs',
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': 'npm:angular-in-memory-web-api',
    },

    // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
    packages: {
      app: {
        main: './main.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      rxjs: {
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'angular-in-memory-web-api': {
        main: './index.js',
        defaultExtension: 'js'
      },
      'ng2-pagination': {
        main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' 
      } 
    }
  });
})(this);
```

Comment: Can you please add your `systemjs.config.js` file content?

Comment: Updated @Supamiu.

Comment: you need to initialzie your `form` object. As it is a static class you property in pomponent will have no value. If you want to share this value between components, best idea is to create service and then inject it into components

Comment: @Vardius Thanks. I'll try to create service.

Comment: You maybe simply made a typo (Form.ts is the class's file, you import from '../form')

Comment: @Supamiu sorry, my bad. Actually, it was small letter.

Comment: Have you tried importing it like this:      import Form from '../Form'; I mean without {} after all you only are exporting one class.

Answer (score 0):

Now you need to initialzie your form object.

```
export class BalanceComponent {
    form: Form;

    constructor() {
        this.form = new Form();
    }
}
```

If you want to share this value between components, best idea is to create service and then inject it into components.

```
export class BalanceComponent {    
    constructor(private formService:FormService) {}
}
```

If you say `private formService:FormService` inside contructor. You will be able later to access this variable like `this.formService`.

```
@Injectable()
export class FormService {
    constructor(){
        var today = new Date(),
            dd = today.getDate(),
            mm = today.getMonth() + 1,
            yyyy = today.getFullYear();

        if(dd < 10) dd = `0${dd}`;
        if(mm < 10) mm = `0${mm}`;

        today = `${yyyy}-${mm}-${dd}`;

        this.balance.dateTo = today;
    }

    public balance = {
        viewBy: 'Ad1',
        companyUnit: 'DEPED',
        financialYear: '2016',
        clients: 'Dummy Text 1'
    };
}
```

Keep in mind that if your service is in shared module, you may get multiple instances of it. Best idea then is to configure module with `Module.forRoot`.

> By convention, the forRoot static method both provides and configures
>   services at the same time. It takes a service configuration object and
>   returns a ModuleWithProviders.

Here is full [Doc](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/ngmodule.html#!#core-for-root) about it.

> Call forRoot only in the root application module, AppModule. Calling
>   it in any other module, particularly in a lazy loaded module, is
>   contrary to the intent and is likely to produce a runtime error.
>
> Remember to import the result; don't add it to any other @NgModule
>   list.

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [CommonModule],
    declarations: [BalanceComponent],
    exports: [BalanceComponent]
})
export class SharedModule {
    static forRoot(): ModuleWithProviders {
        return {
            ngModule: SharedModule,
            providers: [FormService]
        };
    }
}
```

Then import module looks like:

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    /** other modules import **/
    SharedModule.forRoot(), // you can also pass some config here if needed
    routing
  ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```